# Inject data in file (deleting data without overwriting original content)

Tags: c#, file, inject

I've been researching about this. Haven't find an answer about it.
Is it possible to insert/delete data to a file without overwriting it? I know there's `File.AppendAllText(Path, "Content");` but what about deleting it?

For example.

We got a `"Things.CB"` File. The content of this file is:

```
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
-6
-7
-8
-9
-10
```

I want to delete 7 and 4.

I open the File with my program and then proceed to read this numbers into a `List<String>`.

When this happens, after doing a `RemoveAt()` to the list, I got to serialize the file and then save it with a `BinaryWriter` or a `streamWriter`.

In this process, we did 2 things, read the whole file, deserializate and then serializate it so we can write it again.

I want to know if it's possible to only open the file, check position of the text then delete/insert and just save it without serializate or reading into list/arrays/etc...

Comment: Are you prepared to go to a very low level and tamper with the clusters on the hard drive?  You can modify the FAT (NTFS..whatever) so that you essentially fragment the file, moving over the part you want to delete.  Then you have changed absolutely no disk contents except the FAT (or whatever the File Allocation Table is called in your particular OS)

Comment: With random access to files you could *overwrite* the contents (for example, with empty spaces), but not *delete* (making a 20 bytes file a 16 bytes ones, after 'deleting' 4 and 7). And, IIRC, random access will just load the entire sector or in memory, do the changes and write it back again... (no, you cannot partially write in a sector).

Comment: I am not sure if i'm prepared but i can start learning, is possible to do this with C#? or do i have to use a low level lang like c++?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS, if you are on FAT/NTFS you could use Microsoft API functions to play with the FAT/NTFS structure for a certain file.

Consider that you have three parts to your file...1,2,3.  You want to delete Part 2.  So you would manipulate the FAT so that the end of Part 1 now points to the start of Part 3 - effectively dropping Part 2 from the FAT and making it appear deleted.  Then you have not moved any data, simply changed the various clusters and position markers for the file in the FAT.

You would use the same technique for inserting data... Simply adjust the 'pointers' stored in the FAT (file index) so that your new data is in the position you want in the file. Without moving any of your file contents.

These API functions are commonly used by defragmenting programs (Use this term for google searches) and have full access to the file structures (Although I'm not entirely sure that they have enough dynamics for you to skirt around data you want to delete, without moving the other file contents.  They should though).  To go to a lower level would require C / C++, and could become extremely dangerous (backup everything) and hardware specific.  You can access APIs with C#/VB.NET although it is a bit tedious, something like VB6 would be surprisingly quicker to develop around the API functions, although its clunky for general coding.

This will not work over networks, so will only work on drives physically managed by your OS.  This may also not work if you want to delete very tiny bits of data, as the granularity of the FAT management functions may not go that small.